# How to enable a the php_soap extension from .user.ini (no acces to php.ini)

Tags: web-hosting, php

Our application is being hosted on GoDaddy (plesk). We need to enable 'php_soap' extension for our application to work. We contacted the customer support that we don't have access to `php.ini` file to do so but they told us that we can use `.user.ini` instead.
We've tried doing that but `.user.ini` doesn't seem to enable `php_soap` extension when we added the line.

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

after testing if `.user.ini` works at all by changing another setting `upload_max_filesize` and it works. But enabling the `soap` extension doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently our client's host plan was "Shared Hosting" which was restricted by GoDaddy to not have access to the SOAP extension specifically for performance reasons.
We changed the hosting plan and the problem is solved.